# Solve System of Linear Differential Equations with Matrix Math and Lapalace

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Say you have the following system:

$y'=Ay$

$y_{1,2}'(t) =\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}y_{1,2}(t)$

$\mathcal{L}(y')=\mathcal{L}(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}y)$

$sY[s]-y(0)=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}Y[s]$

$sY[s]-(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix})Y[s]=y(0)$

$(Is-\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix})Y[s]=y(0)$

$Y[s]=(Is-\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix})^{-1}y(0)$

$Y[s]=(Is-\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix})^{-1}y(0)$

$Y[s]=(\begin{bmatrix}(s-a)&b\\c&(s-d)\end{bmatrix})^{-1}y(0)$

$Y[s]=\frac{1}{(s-d)(s-a)}\begin{bmatrix}(s-d)&-b\\-c&(s-a)\end{bmatrix}y(0)$

$y(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\frac{1}{(s-d)(s-a)}\begin{bmatrix}(s-d)&-b\\-c&(s-a)\end{bmatrix}y(0))$

If the eigen values,  $\lambda_{1,2}$, were real,

Why do I not get something along the lines of $y_1(t)=c_1 e^{\lambda_1t}+c_2 e^{\lambda_2t}$ and instead I get $y_1(t)=(c_1 e^{\lambda_1t}+c_2 e^{\lambda_2t})y(0)$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are actual values provided by the inverse laplace.

since $y(0)$ is just an unknown initial value, as long as it is just a constant does that mean this is the same thing?

Are there any bad assumptions I might be making?

Comment: Looks fine to me and the constants will come out the same either way.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Paul!